# Is this find query erroring because I am inputting too large of a number?

Tags: c++, mongodb-query

I'm attempting to write a C++ program that finds a location and reads in its data. I need to query a mongodb, where I am storing information about a location in each document.

I have created a connection to the database and can find all documents in a collection. When I attempt to build a find() query that matches a location based on its lat and long I get the error:

```
ReadStationData.cc:109:64: error: narrowing conversion of ‘3.9400500000000001e+1’ from ‘double’ to ‘std::size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
       auto cursor = coll.find({{"lat" , 39.400500000000000966}});
```

My code:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <bsoncxx/builder/basic/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/builder/basic/kvp.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/stdx/make_unique.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/logger.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/options/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp;
    using bsoncxx::builder::basic::make_document;

mongocxx::instance inst{bsoncxx::stdx::make_unique};

    try {
        const auto uri = mongocxx::uri{"mongodb://user:pswd@32.445.67.89/snowdb?authSource=admin"};

        mongocxx::options::client client_options;
        if (uri.ssl()) {
            mongocxx::options::ssl ssl_options;
            client_options.ssl_opts(ssl_options);
        }
        auto client = mongocxx::client{uri, client_options};
        auto admin = client["admin"];
        auto result = admin.run_command(make_document(kvp("isMaster", 1)));

        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(result) << "\n";


    mongocxx::database db = client["snowdb"];
    mongocxx::collection coll = db["Location"];

using bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp;
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::make_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::basic::make_document;

      auto cursor = coll.find({{"lat" , 39.400500000000000966}});

        for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
            std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
}
}
```

Here's how the data looks:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5d02ea10f21300007c1b7274" }, 
"lat" : [ 41.0367999999999995 ], 
"lon" : [ -105.12600000000000477 ], .....
```

Comment: The error is telling you that you're trying to pass a `double` to something that wants a `size_t` (aka `unsigned long`).

Comment: Thanks. Do I just need to convert this to a long unsigned int? How can that be done (doesn't an int not allow for decimal places?)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this was that the data value was in a list [] and I didn't surround the value with an array, as shown here:

`auto cursor=coll.find(make_document(kvp("lon", make_array(-105.12000000000000455))));`